# PowerPress mobile media player

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, media, mobile

I am using the MediaElement media player for PowerPress, everything is working fine. The one thing I noticed is on mobile...affecting the podcast showing first.

If you go to: http://joshrodg.com/hallmark/ scroll down to the Latest Media section. The very first `li` is the culprit. If you click play, you'll notice the duration causes the player to display all funky. I removed the duration, but the player still appears off. The weird thing is that it's only affecting the first `li`, the other `li's` appear to be ok.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I could possible fix this besides using a different player?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a bandaid, but it'll work for my project. I noticed this behavior seems to be related to the duration of my podcast exceeding an hour - and seems to be isolated to just mobile browsers. So, what I did was just hide the overflow (which may not work for everyone):

```
/* MediaElement */
.mejs-container[style] {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

The duration just isn't shown for that podcast, not ideal, but it works. The main thing is the audio file plays without the funky behavior...the play/pause still works...and all of the audio files that have a duration under an hour display the duration just fine and work without issue.

For me this works because it really doesn't disrupt the user experience. I would prefer the duration to be shown, but that's not a deal breaker because there is a progress bar so the user can still gauge how much time is left for a given podcast.

Unfortunately, in this situation (besides switching audio players), this is a pretty good solution and will work for me. Most users probably won't even notice and having a podcast over an hour is not the norm for this site, so having it work this way is a great solution.

Thanks,
Josh